# Javascript: Variable scope and usage order

Tags: javascript, ajax

I came across a peculiar issue when trying to make an ajax call and isolate the actions of the function to itself. Here is the code snippet

```js
$(document).on('click', 'input.action', function(event) {
    var self = this;
    $.ajax({
        url:'http://date.jsontest.com/',
        method:'GET',
        cache:false,
        dataType:'json',
        success:self.process,
        error:function(){self.process(false);}
    });
    
    self.process = function(data) {
        if (data) {
            
            alert(data.time);
        }
        
        else {
            alert("Operation Failed!");
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <input type="button" value="Get Time" class="action"/>
</div>
```

Let me briefly explain what I am trying to do, on click of the button, I wish to receive some data from the server and display the data. I am using a `process` function to process the received data. In case of an error I reuse the `process` function in a different way to display the error message. I simply use the `self` variable to contain all the elements within the parent function. I fully understand the following:

### What I know

1. I do not **have** to use the `self` to contain the `process` function because another method will not have access to it
2. Because the `process` method in the snippet above is declared after the ajax call for the program as far as it is concerned the `process` function is undefined.
3. I clearly know how to fix it.

### Experiment:

1. Click on the `Get Time` button
2. Wait for as long as you want but see no result, which is expected because of the `process` function is declared after the ajax call
3. Click on the `Get Time` button again
4. It works now! Some time (which is probably not your time :P) is displayed now!!

### What I wish to know:

What just happened? why does it work the second time and everytime after? Remember this **only** works for ajax calls, if it were the case that the assignment is retained in the function after calling it once, then this should work in every situation but it does not. Here is an experiment to show that it does not work the same way when ajax calls are not used: [Fiddle - Experiment](http://jsfiddle.net/7hy3he2n/1/)

### The Solution:

I am adding a sample solution based on [@Felix Kling](https://stackoverflow.com/users/218196/felix-kling)'s answer below. In the [Sample Solution](http://jsfiddle.net/c32533a2/1/), there are two buttons `Get Time` and `Get Date`. I've attached the parameter to retrieve `time` in case of `Get Time` and `date` in the case of `Get Date` to the object `self` and it is interesting that once I click on `Get Time` nothing happens just like before but if I click on either `Get Time` or `Get Date` the second time only time is displayed.

Comment: `self.process` is undefined on the first AJAX call. But you define it immediately after the first AJAX call.

Comment: Okay, if that is the case, then lets go to the fiddle experiment In the *What I wish to know* section which does not have an ajax call. as you see there I do the same thing but the second click does not do anything.

Comment: Your fiddle experiment is not equivalent. The ajax call should see a result even the first time around, not the way you explain. That's because you make an ajax call, which will call `self.process` when it receives a reply. `self.process` is undefined at the point you call `ajax` but it doesn't matter. You then define `self.process`. At the end of your script, once there's nothing else to run, javascript will make the ajax request. Once ajax gets a response it will call `self.process`. At this point it is no longer undefined so it should succeed.

Comment: What just happened has something to do with [declaration hoisting](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_hoisting.asp).

Comment: @woozyking: No, there is no function declaration here.

Comment: @slebetman: The ajax call does not call `self.process`. It calls the value that `self.process` as at the time the ajax call is made. At the first time that is `undefined`, so the first ajax call with not execute the success handler.

Comment: @FelixKling: Ah, yes, I missed it. There is no closure so the variable is passed by value. The error callback on the other hand should work because it is passed as a closure. Can't believe I missed that.

Comment: @slebetman: And I missed the `error` handler :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What just happened?

In a simplified way, this:

```
var process;
// First click
ajaxCall(process); // process is still undefined
process = function() { ... };

// second click
ajaxCall(process); // process is defined
process = function() { ... };
```

The assignment to `self.process` "persists" between events because `self` refers to the same element.

> Here is an experiment to show that it does not work the same way when ajax calls are not used: ...

It doesn't work in your fiddle because of one big difference: you are trying to execute `process` immediately. But it doesn't exist, so an error is thrown. At this point the script terminates and won't execute the rest of the function, where the function definition takes place.

In your example here, the execution of `process` is delayed. The script "doesn't know" that there is no function to call until the response was received.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing "special" going on here. Yes, accepted that the first time it returns `undefined` as it is yet to be defined.

But, you're attaching the function to the *same* element `input.action`. So, the next time, when you click the button, `this` *already* has the `process` method attached to it, so gets called when clicked again.

Try adding one more button with same class and click each once. Now though you've clicked the first button, clicking the second button will still not create an `alert` as it has not *yet* had the `process` function attached to it.